# Bootstrap Modal Dialog Not Displaying (Angular)

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

This issue is specific to IE.

My project is using Angular (1.4) and the UI Bootstrap component.

When launching a modal, the modal dialog appears fine on Chrome. However in IE only the backdrop displays, but not the modal dialog (content).

The modal appears in the code and all styles seem to be applied. If I manually inspect the modal dialog I can see that its inline style is set to display block.

If I uncheck this style and recheck the style, in web inspector, the modal dialog displays as normal.

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="modal fade ng-isolate-scope in" role="dialog" style="display: block; z-index: 1050;" ng-class="{in: animate}" ng-click="close($event)" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}" modal-window="" index="0" animate="animate">
```

Comment: First, please format your code correct.
Second, you dont need any inline styles for modals. You should remove them,

Comment: The inline styles are added automatically as part of the angular module, I dont think removing them makes a difference here.